# Bootstrap table, when hover a row can I change content visibility in the last column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am constructing an bootstrap responsive table with 4 columns.

What I would like to achieve, is the default visibility state in the last column should be hidden, but when I hover the respective row the last column in that row should change the content visibility to visible. Is this possible without using javascript?

The Html:

```
<table class="table table-hover table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Header 1</th>
        <th>Header 2</th>
        <th>Header 3</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Row 1</td>
        <td>column 1</td>
        <td>column 2</td>
        <td>column 3 hide</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Row 2</td>
        <td>column 1</td>
        <td>column 2</td>
        <td>column 3 hide</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Row 3</td>
        <td>column 1</td>
        <td>column 2</td>
        <td>column 3 hide</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

and some CSS experiments, this is how far I could go:
(I can identify the last column, but I dont know how to change the visible state)

```
.table-hover tbody tr td:last-child {
    color: #4d4d4d;
    text-decoration:none;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Hope someone can help me with this.
Cheers,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
.table-hover tbody tr:hover td:last-child {
      visibility: visible;
}
```

[Working Example](http://www.bootply.com/120985)

Comment: Hi! The idea is to see also the row, only the content should get Hide and Visible, but that´s not a problem because you put me in the right direction. I use a <span> to track the content and change is state in accordance. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: You are welcome. Glad you could figure the rest out yourself. Happy coding! :)

Comment: @user3463325 Waht do you mean? Just click the `Working Example` link to get to the complete code..